# Run a spring-boot application and its cucumber tests in the same project using one maven "command"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, ant, cucumber

**Overview**

A *maven* project using *spring boot* for which some *cucumber* tests are implemented (in the same project!).

```
src
 |
 |-main
 |  |
 |  |-java
 |     |
 |     |-SpringBootApp
 |     |-Controller
 |
 |-test
   |
   |-java
   |  |
   |  |-cucumbertests
   |       |     
   |       |-StepDefinitions
   |       |-CucumberTestsRunner
   |
   |-resources
        |-features
              |-hello.feature
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

*CucumberTestsRunner*

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = "cucumbertests")
pulic class CucumberTestsRunner {
}
```

*StepDefinitions*

```
public class StepDefinitions {

    private String response;

    @When("I say hello")
    public void iSayHello() {
        // rest assured call
        response = get("<base_url>/hello").extract().asString();
    }

    @Then
    public void iMGreetedWithHello() {
        assertEquals("Hello!", response);
    }
}
```

With this in place,

- I can run in a console `mvn spring-boot:run` (from where the SpringBoot application starts)
- and then in **another console** `mvn test -Dtest=CucumberTestsRunner`, from where the Cucumber tests run against the webservices

So far so good, the tests pass without any issue.

**Problem**

I'd like to be able to issue a **single command** to start the SpringBoot application and then run the tests against the started application. Then after the tests finished, kill the SpringBoot application.

Ideally this is intended to be used in a CI system like Jenkins.

I was exploring the [Apache Maven AntRun plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) as an option, but this is my first time doing this kind of set up and I'm not sure this would be a right approach. Previously I have seen set up like this but on independent projects (tests in a different app than the tested application).

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using cucumber tests instead of usual unit/integration tests for a Spring Boot application?

Comment: @khmarbaise there are unit tests in the project, but we also have Cucumber tests for different purposes.

Comment: As I asked. Why would you like to use cucumber tests? For what purpose? In Spring Boot you can test everything by using the support of Spring Boot (controllers/REST API etc.)...?

Comment: @khmarbaise we're using Cucumber tests to have a living docs, requirement specifications, examples of what cases applies and which don't for each requirements, (kind of) e2e tests, etc. (everything that you may heard of BDD). This may be arguable the best approach (or even necessary in the project), but the fact is this is the current state of the project and the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Also, I'm exploring the option of doing some script (or similar) for Jenkins to do this for me (somehow).

Comment: You should control the cucumber test by using the maven failsafe plugin instead of maven-surefire-plugin which means they will be executed after the package phase which means the whole application is already being built (jar file exist) so you can start your application via ProcessBuilder and run your tests against it.. Apart from that I would think about going to JUnit Jupiter instead of Cucumber cause Cucumber only supports JUnit 4(as far as I know)..which limits several parts.

Comment: Have a look at [spring-boot:start and spring-boot:stop](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals) goals. You could have your tests run in between those two.

Comment: @KenS would you mind posting a formal answer from your comment. I tried this approach and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @khmarbaise Cucumber supports JUnit 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using spring-boot:run in one console and running your tests in a second one, you can use use [spring-boot:start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-start) and [spring-boot:stop](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-stop).

Something like `mvn spring-boot:start test spring-boot:stop` would start the application, run the tests and then stop the application again.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using `mvn spring-boot:start test spring-boot:stop` or to using `mvn verify` and starting the application in the `pre-integration-test` and stopping it in the `post-integration-test` phase you can also use `cucumber-spring` and run the test with Mock MCV.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── Application.java
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── CucumberTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── com
            │   └── example
            │       └── hello.feature
            └── junit-platform.properties
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.5.0</cucumber.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @RestController
    public static class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String local() {
            return "Greetings from Local!";
        }

    }

}
```

```
package com.example;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@Cucumber
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class CucumberTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Given("the application says hello")
    public void getLocalHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/").accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Greetings from Local!")));
    }

}
```

```
Feature: Hello world

  Scenario: Calling a rest end point
    * the application says hello
```